# How to flip month and day in a datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

How can I flip "2012-**12-01** 12:33:00.0" to become "2012-**01-12** 12:33:00.0"? I had tried "select convert(varchar(50), convert(datetime, log_date, 103), 121)" and used both 101 and 103 and still not able to flip it.

The database is MS SQL

Comment: Don't do this in SQL. Do it in the application when you need to display the DateTime.

Comment: No, I can't. The reason is because the data was wrongly populated. So I need to fix the data. The other date fields are in the right format. Hence I can't change the app just for this field. The data has to be corrected.

Comment: How do you mean? Are the dates correct? A DateTime value **does not have a format** - this is just how SSMS shows it to you.

Comment: The dates are wrong. It was inserted as YYYY-DD-MM and because my database is set as YYYY-MM-DD, that's why it read DD as MM and MM as DD. Only that column is wrong. All my other dates column are being inserted at the right YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: If the data is incorrect in the tables you can use Datepart to pull it apart and rebuild it.

Comment: But surely inserts would fail if you had a date such as `2012-31-01` or `2012-01-31`?

Comment: I can use DATEPART to pull all apart, but I do not know how to rebuild it back to be part of the UPDATE statement.

Comment: @Oded, yes, INSERT would fail for your scenario - that, lucky me. But INSERT was successful for 2012-12-01, whereas it should be 2012-01-12

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET DATEFORMAT ydm
SET @date = '2012-12-01 12:33:00.0'
SELECT @date
```

`SET DATEFORMAT ydm` will give you the result in your required format.

**Other Option**

```
UPDATE Table_Name
SET COLUMN_NAME= convert(varchar(20), convert(Date, @date, 101)) +  convert(varchar(30),convert(time, @date))
WHERE
```

**OR**

```
select convert(datetime, convert(varchar(100), @date), 20)
```

Comment: Thanks Hayer, how can I use it as part of the UPDATE statement? There are a lot of records needed to be updated.

Comment: I think the easiest approach is to write function with returns the correct format. But it scan slow the query execution time. There must be a proper way to do this. Try to google.

Answer (score 1):

You could just perform some string manipulation (NOTE: Untested code)

```
UPDATE table
SET date=
  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),date,128),4) -- '2012'
  +SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),date,128),7,3) -- '-01'
  +SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),date,128),4,3) -- '-12'
  +RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),date,128),LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),date,128))-10) -- ' 12:33:00.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Format function to swap day and month, while keeping the year and hour:

```
update MyTable
set [date] = 
FORMAT([date],'yyyy') + '-' +
FORMAT([date],'dd')  + '-' +
FORMAT([date],'MM') + ' ' +
FORMAT([date],'hh:mm:ss')
from MyTable
```